# Fade in/out text overlay image plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a set of images in a directory I would like to cross fade in a loop.  There are about a million jQuery plugins that can accomplish this.  What I haven't found is the ability to cross fade text overlaying the images.  What I don't want to do is have a duplicate copy of each image, one with and one without the text overlay, as this seems entirely wasteful.

jQuery can already fade in/out text along with images, but I have yet to find a way to overlay the image with cross faded text.

Sure, I can do this in Flash...but I would like to not have that requirement for this client's website.

Suggestions?  (I've already googled; haven't found anything)

**Edit:** Text overlay would be programmatic in the loop, it would not be based on mouseover.  This is just a loop of images on the front page of a site along with text fading in and out over each image

Comment: Most of the plugins concentrate on content rather than images. Maybe With absolute positioning and zindex you can put the image behind text and use any of the plugins to fade-in/out the text.

Comment: The only possible solution I can find is a semi-transparent overlay caption demonstrated here: http://www.queness.com/post/152/simple-jquery-image-slide-show-with-semi-transparent-caption  and then updated here: http://www.queness.com/post/1450/jquery-photo-slide-show-with-slick-caption-tutorial-revisited  This might just have to work for what I am looking for...unless someone has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution seems to be this: [Photo Slide Show With Slick Caption](http://www.queness.com/post/1450/jquery-photo-slide-show-with-slick-caption-tutorial-revisited)